# Is there another way to render in ReactJs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs. From the examples, I can see that one needs to call
`React.render(elementToBeReadered, targetingElement)`. Is there a way to use the web components defined in React directly, like angularjs' directive? E.g.

```
<Hello />

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
    );
  }
});
```

So that I don't need to add a target element like `<div id='target-element'></div>` and then render it with `React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('target-element'))`. Why should I duplicate this everywhere?

Comment: Render is a key part of the virtual DOM. But, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: if you aren't using ngReact, you can take a look it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll typically nest react components within each other. In angular, this would be similar to having many `ng-app` on many different elements.

If you want to have regular DOM, with react components only sparsely populated, then you'll have to render by element reference as you said. I would try to use react components to compose the entire app instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "this would be similar to having many ng-app on many different elements". Could you articulate more?
What I really want to achieve is that, you can image, that the DOM (with directives) keeps the same, but I can replace angular implementation with React implimentation.

Comment: What I mean is `ng-app` is the entry point to an angular app, much the same way as `React.render`. I would suggest you make one react component that wraps all the sub components along with the regular dom.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use the web components defined in React directly, like angularjs' directive?

Sure, you can build any system you like on top of React.render.  You give it a react element and a dom node, and it does its thing.  You could build an angular directive that renders the component you like, for example:

```
var reactComponents = {Foo: Foo};
module.directive('react', function($parse){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var props = Object.keys(attrs).reduce(function(props, key){
        if (key === "component") return props;
        props[key] = $parse(attrs[key])(scope);
        return props;
      }, {});
      var reactElement = React.createElement(reactComponents[attrs.component], props);
      React.render(reactElement, element);
    }
  };
});
```

<sup>not tested</sup>

And in your template:

```
<react component="Foo" bar="1" baz="something.otherThing"></react>
```

If you add some watchers it'll respond to expressions changing, and you can do other things like error handling, resolving the component class with $injector rather than a static object hash, and handling '$destroy' (see React.unmountComponentAtNode).

Comment: This is different because in the DOM the node name is not the React class name. I hope I can just write `<Foo bar="1" baz="something.otherThing" />`. Please see my comment for another answer.

Comment: @XiaoPeng You would need to create a directive for each component you wanted to use in this way. A custom provider similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368066/angularjs-extending-module-with-own-types-providers/16378879#16378879) that delegates to the directive registration method might help.

Comment: @XiaoPeng this is a pretty bad idea.  I was just providing an example of how you could do it, not how you should.  I currently just create a directive for each mini application written in react. Mixing angular and react doesn't work well, but having small react applications in angular applications is working well for me.